# How did I stop IllegalStateExceptions from being thrown with LayoutInflater().inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, layout-inflater, illegalstateexception

I recently recently ran into an issue while setting up a viewpager with 3 fragments. When the application ran it crashed with a

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first
```

Here is the code for creating list list of fragments to pass to the pageAdapter.

```
private Vector<Fragment> getFragments() {
    Vector<Fragment> list = new Vector<Fragment>();

    list.add(new Fragment1());
    list.add(new Fragment2());
    list.add(new Fragment3());

    return list;
```

Each of the fragments were essentially the same except for a being created with different layouts. Here was the original code I had for one of the fragments. 
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container);
    return v;
}
}
```

But when I ran it like this it kept crashing with the IllegalStateException. I found that the issue was coming from the fragments being created. After some Googling I tried changing the code for the fragment to this.

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

    return v;
}
}
```

This resolved the issue and I no longer got the IllegalStateException except I have no idea how this worked. What exactly does this boolean do? And what does this exception mean? I had tried adding the method call like it suggusted but that did not resolve it. Also I tried changing this boolean to true and I got the same error again. The android docs say its attachToRoot but isn't that what I want to do? Attach my 3 fragments to the rootview, which is the viewpager? If anyone could explain this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The boolean parameter of the 3-arg version of `LayoutInflater.inflate()` determines whether the `LayoutInflater` will add the inflated view to the specified container. For fragments, you should specify `false` because the Fragment itself will add the returned View to the container. If you pass `true` or use the 2-arg method, the LayoutInflater will add the view to the container, then the Fragment will try to do so again later, which results in the `IllegalStateException`.